# Why does Django throw 'invalid literal for int() with base 10' error when I use a foreign key?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I need to build a user model in django that will have specific properties especially a profile picture.

Each user belongs to a particular group and each user has their individual conversation history.

Below is the conversation model and the group (Contexts) model

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    context_name = models.CharField(null=False,max_length=100)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    data = models.TextField(null=False)

class Contexts(models.Model):
    context_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    context_description = models.TextField()
    users = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

def getUserImagePath(instance,filename):
    return "/kriktona/static/%s_%s"% (str(time()).replace('.','_'),filename)

class UserProperty(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to=getUserImagePath, default="/kriktona/static/images/user.png" ,null=True)
    org = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
```

As you can see, in `Conversation` model, `user` was just a field which I would use to filter the conversation based on the particular user and in `Contexts` model, `users` is just the field where I pass in the user and filter by that.So I get the group (Contexts) for which the user is part of.

This setup works just fine but now I need to declare a seperate user model which will have its own name and picture.

For `Conversation` model, I don't need to do anything since I just need to filter the conversation by the user's name.

So I do something like

```
Conversation.objects.filter(
            user=user_request.get("user")).filter(context_name=user_request.get("context_name"))
```

However for the `Contexts`, I need to show the users that belong to that particular context with their profile picture (just like in a Facebook group).

So I define a `UserProperty` model in `model.py`

```
class UserProperty(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to=getUserImagePath, default="/static/images/user.png" ,null=True)
    org = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
```

And change the `Contexts` field accordingly

```
class Contexts(models.Model):
    context_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    context_description = models.TextField()
    users = models.ForeignKey(UserProperty , related_name='context_users')
```

I also make appropriate changes in postgres tables too.

Below is the UserProperty table (*webhook_userproperty*)

```
  Column  |          Type          | Modifiers 
----------+------------------------+-----------
 id       | integer                | 
 username | character varying(100) | 
 pic      | bytea                  | 
 org      | character varying(100) | 


Indexes:
    "webhook_userproperty_username_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (username)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "webhook_contexts" CONSTRAINT "webhook_contexts_users_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (users) REFERENCES webhook_userproperty(username) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Below is the `Contexts` table (webhook_contexts)

```
       Column        |          Type          | Modifiers 
---------------------+------------------------+-----------
 id                  | integer                | 
 context_name        | character varying(100) | 
 context_description | character varying(100) | 
 users               | text                   | 
Foreign-key constraints:
    "webhook_contexts_users_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (users) REFERENCES webhook_userproperty(username) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

But then I get the below error when the page loads

```
ERROR 2018-08-12 10:22:13,585 django.request Internal Server Error: /api/contexts
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/webhook/ui_server.py", line 279, in get_contexts
    queryset = serializers.serialize("json", Contexts.objects.filter(users=user_request.get("user")))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 782, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 800, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1261, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1287, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1217, in build_filter
    condition = lookup_class(lhs, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py", line 112, in get_prep_lookup
    self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 962, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'test@email.com
```

I have no clue as to why am I getting this error.It worked fine earlier when I didn't have to define any User model but now it throws error though I made the necessary changes in the `models.py` file and the postgres tables.

I think it must have something to do with the way I have defined the foreign key.What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

This is my function when to show the contexts (groups)

```
@csrf_exempt
def get_contexts(request):
    user_request = request.GET
    queryset = serializers.serialize("json", Contexts.objects.filter(users=user_request.get("user")))
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps([i.get('fields') for i in json.loads(queryset)]))
```

**UPDATE**

Currently I receive an error like below

```
ProgrammingError: column webhook_contexts.users_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...k_contexts" INNER JOIN "webhook_userproperty" ON ("webhook_c...
```

I think the problem might be the way I am creating the `webhook_userproperty`.This is how I create the table in postgres

```
CREATE TABLE webhook_userproperty(id integer, username character varying(100) unique, pic bytea, org character varying(100));
```

Here I am assigning `unique` to `username` since I am referring it to the table webhook_contexts via a foreign key.But as soon as I create it, I get the following warning

```
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / UNIQUE will create implicit index "webhook_userproperty_username_key" for table "webhook_userproperty"
```

Then I create the `webhook_contexts` with the following query

```
CREATE TABLE webhook_contexts(id integer, context_name character varying(100), context_description character varying(100) , users text REFERENCES webhook_userproperty(username) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Not sure if the warning could be reason behind this error.

Comment: do you have views? please add them

Comment: How the error occurred? While trying to create **`Contexts`** instance?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge added.

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge yes when I use this query `queryset = serializers.serialize("json", Contexts.objects.filter(users=user_request.get("user")))`.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the name of the `ForeignKey` should be singular, In the `Contexts` model please change `users` to `user` and the `related_name` should be `contexts`

```
class Contexts(models.Model):
    context_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    context_description = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProperty , related_name='contexts')  # <- user
```

and if you are the getting username then get all the contexts like

```
Contexts.objects.filter(user__username=user_request.get("user"))
```